# is it possible to retrieve the current value in sharepoint list item before save

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, splistitem

I have a sharepoint list. On the edit form of list item i have a custom action button to send the mail containg the contents of the list columns . If the user changes any value in a column and then clicks the custom action button, the new column value is not retrived. Is it possible to retrieve the edited value before clicking save on edit form.

I am using `_spGetQueryParam('id')` to retrive the current id.

Comment: is it possible to retrive the value of textbox before save click, not necessary sharepoint in that case

Comment: yes it is easy using Jquery. Use `$("input[title=Title]").val()` to read the value of a field named `Title'